# Misplaced semicolon in for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

When I am doing my assignments I done a small mistake by placing ; in the    for loop like the following code.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++);{
    n=n*i;
}
```

When I compiled the program its compiled with no error but I did not get the output for a while. Then later figured out that I misplaced the semicolon in for loop. What was the bug when I place semicolon after for loop.

```
class A
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int i, n=1;
        for(i=1; i<=5; i++);
        n=n*i;
        System.out.println(n);
    }    
}
```

I am getting output for the following code as 6 instead of 120.

Comment: You made the `for` loop consist entirely of an empty statement. The loop was then followed by your block in braces, but that block wasn't part of the loop.

Comment: The compiler never reaches and executes the block inside the brackets.

Comment: i highly doubt this code will do what you want. apart from the syntax-error, `n` will always be 0 after the loop, if `n >= 0` or `n`, if `n < 0`

Comment: @gunner - incorrect, it will execute the line inside the braces one time with the current values of `i` and `n`

Comment: @Paul - Please explain. #1: there is no syntax error. #2: At the end of the loop `i` will have the value of `n` and given the code we have here there is no way for us to tell what the value of `n` was/is

Comment: @KevinDTimm under the assumtion that the misplaced semicolon is removed, we have two options: the code in the loop doesn't execute, because `n <= 0`, so `n` won't change. Or `n > 0`, now the first run through the loop will be with `n = ?` and `i = 0`, so after `n = n * i`, `n` will be 0 and the loop breaks off

Comment: Sorry for the intereption can I know why the output is coming as 6 in #2

Comment: @KevinDTimm you are right, I had in mind it wouldn't be reached by the for loop. But yes, because i is previously declared there will be no compiler error.

Comment: @Ranga Ganesh, before the code reached to the n=n*1 block, your for loop executes untill the value of i becomes greater than 5 which is after i=6. you have set n=1 already. so when n=n*1 executes, you have n=6*1 , resulting your sys.out to 6.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was asked and answered then changed by the OP to become a completely different question.

Comment: @KevinDTimm I have already stated I am new to this site. So any mistakes excuse it

Comment: As developers we should know better than to submit half of our work - it's our responsibility to ask correct questions with at least the minimum amount of information necessary to retrieve an answer.  Posting a subset of the question without pertinent data shows an incredible lack of preparation and concern for the time of other people.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok got it. Wont repeat it hear afters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you place semicolon after a for loop then it is technically correct syntax. Because it is considered as an empty statement - that means nothing to execute.

In your case -

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++);
```

An empty statement executed up to `n` times. Or in other words the `for-loop` simply runs `n` times.

The curly braces `{}` after the for loop executed only once. Now the code block inside the curly braces `{}` considered as a [floating block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514583/is-there-a-use-of-free-floating-block-inside-a-method-in-java).

Answer (score 3):

When you do this: `for(i=0;i<n;i++);` you are essentially doing this: `for(i=0;i<n;i++) {}`. This translates to a loop with no body.

This also happens for `while` loops: `while(..);{<Foo>}`. The extra `;` will make  execute only once.

The same goes for `if` statements. Doing `if(a==b);{<Foo>}` will still execute `<Foo>` for the same reason. If `a == b`, then, the empty statement will be taken into consideration. Afterwards, `<Foo>` will be executed. This can give the wrong impression that Java will treat a `false` as a `true` since if `a != b`, then, `<Foo>` would still be executed.

Answer (score 1):

`for` loop can execute only one code block or one statement, even empty ones. So semicolon here represents empty statement (statement which does nothing).

In other words you can think of `for(int i; i<n; i++);` as `for(int i; i<n; i++){}`.

So code like

```
for(int i; i<n; i++);{
    foo();
}
```

is same as

```
for(int i; i<n; i++){
    //do nothing, except i++
}
//after loop finishes 
{
    foo();
}
```

and

```
for(int i; i<n; i++);
    foo();
```

is simply

```
for(int i; i<n; i++){
}
foo();
```

---

About

> ```
> int i, n=1;
> for(i=1; i<=5; i++);
> n=n*i;
> System.out.println(n);
> ```
>
> I am getting output for the following code as 6 instead of 120.

As explained earlier your code

```
for(i=1; i<=5; i++);
n=n*i;
```

is same as

```
for(i=1; i<=5; i++){}
n=n*i;
```

which means that it your loop will not execute `n=n*i` but will try to execute `{}` which does nothing. Also at end of each iteration `i` will be incremented because of `i++` so when `i` will become `5` your and `i<5` will be false flow of control will leave loop and will execute `n=n*5` which means that n will become `n=1*5` which is `5`.

If you want to get as result `120` by executing `n=n*i` in each loop simply remove semicolon after loop.

```
for(i=1; i<=5; i++)//<--removed semicolon
    n=n*i;
```

BTW prefer to place code which should be executed by loop or `if` statement in code blocks,

```
for(i=1; i<=5; i++){
    n=n*i;
}
```

This makes your code easier to read and maintain. Also if you will make again your mistake and you will use some auto formatting tool which will indent your code for you you will see that it will be formatted as

```
for(i=1; i<=5; i++)
    ;
{
    n=n*i;
}
```

which makes spotting such errors very easy.

Comment: class A
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
int i,n=1;
for(i=1;i<=5;i++);
n=n*i;
System.out.println(n);
}
}

Comment: @RangaGanesh This doesn't change much. `for` loop can execute only one code block, or one statement, even if code blocks or statements are empty.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't get an output because the semi-colon ended the statement, [ for(I = 0; I < n; I++ ]

The code should be:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
     n=n*1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting 6 is simple. At the last iteration the value of i turns from 5 to 6, the loop won't do another iteration because i=6 and it doesn't satisfy the condition for the `for loop` any more. Since n=1 and i=6 then the output of n*i is 6.