# Print inside Switch

Tags: java, switch-statement

Desired outcome is printing "i is zero" then one, two, three, four..

It seems like my for loop is working properly, `i` is getting to 5 every time I execute but none of my cases are true, so nothing is printing. What am I doing wrong?

```java
public class SwitchTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;

        for ( i=0; i < 5; i++); {

        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("i is zero");
            case 1:
                System.out.println("i is one");
            case 2:
                System.out.println("i is two");
            case 3:
                System.out.println("i is three");
            case 4:
                System.out.println("i is four");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a semicolon before the opening curly brace in the for-loop.

Comment: You need breaks after the prints in your switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing gets printed because there's a semicolon after your `for` statement, and java doesn't complain because [it's still valid syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30485019/7096763). But fix it and you'll find that *all* of your cases print out on every iteration. This is because a `switch` statement will execute from the relevant case, all the way to the bottom, unless you end each case statement by a `break`:

```
switch (i) {
    case 0:
        System.out.println("i is zero");
        break; //"break" means "exit the switch block here, don't go any further"
    case 1:
        System.out.println("i is one");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("i is two");
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("i is three");
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("i is four");
        break; //This one is optional
}
```

For good style, you should also include a `default` case, but that's a story for another day...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `break` statement after every Sysout like.

```java
switch (i) {
           case 0:
                System.out.println("i is zero");
                break;
            case 1:
                System.out.println("i is one");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("i is two");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("i is three");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("i is four");
                break;
            default:
               //some statement here.

     }
```