# Kotlin: how to limit scope within a block?

Tags: kotlin

In Java one can use curly braces to delineate [a block of code with its own scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4514583/86967):

```
void f() {
  {
    int x = 1
    // do something with x
  }

  // x not visible here anymore
}
```

How is this done in Kotlin?

Comment: Same applies to Kotlin

Comment: @Moira which is the scope of any variable declared in it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `run` for this purpose:

> `inline fun <R> run(block: () -> R): R` [(source)](http://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.2.50/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/util/Standard.kt#L38)
>   Calls the specified function block and returns its result.
>
> <sub>[kotlin.run](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html)</sub>

```
fun f() {
    run {
        val x = 1
        // do something with x
    }
    // x not visible here anymore
}
```

This is an inline function (like many other language construct-like functions in Kotlin), so performance-wise it's equivalent to the Java code.

---

`{}` doesn't work since it creates a lambda (which is never actually invoked, so it does nothing). You could call it immediately (`{ foo }()`) with the overhead of creating a lambda, or create an inline function that does this for you - which is exactly what `run` does.

Comment: This is MUCH easier to type and understand than java.  I'll never think that this is some sort of weird class with a function called run--I'll immediately realize that this is simply a scoping mechanism.  I'm so glad google is forcing us to switch to this beautiful and obvious language that never needs explaining.

Answer (score 0):

```
do {
    int x = 1
    // do something with x
} while (false)

// x not visible here anymore
```

As for today, this works perfectly, while "if (true) {...}" causes a warning "Condition is always 'true'".